# what is the unit of this rate of change?

Tags: functions, elementary-functions, slope

I'm given a table that shows the percent of Canadian households that used e-mail from year A to year B. Then what is the unit of the average rate of change of the percent of households using e-mails from year A to year B? Is it *percent per year*? I'm fine with dollars per year, miles per hour and so forth, but percent per year seems weird to me.

Comment: Yes, it would be percent per year.

Comment: Percent terminology can be a bit tricky. Suppose the values were $10\%$ in $2000$, and $20\%$ in $2001$. In a strict "unit-per-unit" sense, they rose "$10\%$ per year"; and yet, usage *doubled*, so it's also correct to say that it rose by "$100\%$ per year". To avoid confusion, we can use "percentage points" to describe changes in calculated percents;  hence, "$100$ percent/year" vs "$10$ *percentage-points*/year". ... Note: People are often casually careless —and sometimes intentionally deceptive— about this distinction. For the particular question, the distinction might be unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

The unit of the average rate of change of the percent of households using e-mail from year A to year B would indeed be percent per year.

Here's why:

When we talk about the rate of change, we're essentially talking about how much something changes over time. In this case, the percentage of households using e-mail is changing over a period of time from year A to year B.

Percent is a unit of measurement that represents a portion of 100. So, when we say "percent per year," we're expressing the change in percentage over the course of one year.

For example, if the percentage of households using e-mail increased from $30%$ in year A to $40%$ in year B over a span of 5 years, the average rate of change would be $(40% - 30%) / 5 years = 2%$ per year. This means that, on average, the percentage of households using e-mail increased by $2%$ each year during that time period.